# Check Android Network continuously

Tags: android, networking

I want to verify the Android system networks continuously in this way, but i think that in this form is not correct, my service should update if the connection on wifi or other network is available.

```
public class ObjService extends Service{

    private final static int NOTIFICATION=1;
    public static boolean process;
    private NotificationManager state;
    private NotificationCompat.Builder objBuilder;

    public void onCreate(){
     process=true;
    state=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);    
    objBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.launchimg))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_img);



  Thread checker=new Thread(){//1
    public void run(){//2
    while (process){//3
    if (verifyConnection()){//4
      updateNotificationService("Service is available");
    }else{
     updateNotificationService("Service is not available");
    }//4
     try{
       Thread.sleep(6000);
     }catch(InterruptedException e){
      //..printLog..
     }
    }//3
   };//2

};//1
checker.start();
.
.
.
```

my function verifyConnection() is:

```
public boolean verifyConnection() {

        boolean flag = true;

      ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

       NetworkInfo[] net = connec.getAllNetworkInfo();

       if (!net[0].isAvailable() && !net[1].isAvailable())
       {
           flag = false;

       }
       return flag;  

    }
```

updateNotificationService() is:

```
public void updateNotificacionService(String arg){

objBuilder.setContentText(arg)
.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());

state.notify(NOTIFICATION, objBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: P.S Excuse my english if is wrong.

Comment: use  [this](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-internet-connection-status-network-change/) link for checking network status

Comment: use this link -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14634074/notify-activity-of-network-change-android Hope this helps you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783117/network-listener-android this will help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code below to listen whether the connection exist, if the connection state changes it notifies the change,

```
public class NetworkStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 super.onReceive(context, intent);
 Log.d("app","Network connectivity change");
 if(intent.getExtras()!=null) {
    NetworkInfo ni=(NetworkInfo) intent.getExtras().get(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
    if(ni!=null && ni.getState()==NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
        Log.i("app","Network "+ni.getTypeName()+" connected");
    }
 }
 if(intent.getExtras().getBoolean(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY,Boolean.FALSE)) {
        Log.d("app","There's no network connectivity");
 }
}
}
```

Then for manifest,

```
<receiver android:name=".NetworkStateReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Reference: [Internet listener Android example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12157130/internet-listener-android-example)

Comment: Thanks so much, for your answer. That's more simple than thread running continuously.

Answer (score 0):

> **Android 7.0 (API level 24)** placed limitations on broadcasts, as
>   described in [Background Optimization](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/background-optimization). **Android 8.0 (API level 26)** makes
>   these limitations more stringent.
>
> Apps can use `Context.registerReceiver()` at runtime to register a
>   receiver for any broadcast, whether implicit or explicit.

Documentation [reference](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts).

So, here is a utility class that utilizes a context registered [`BroadcastReceiver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver) , and [`LifeCycleObserver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/LifecycleObserver) for achieving [Single-responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle)

```
class ConnectionUtil implements LifecycleObserver {

    private ConnectivityManager mConnectivityMgr;
    private Context mContext;
    private NetworkStateReceiver mNetworkStateReceiver;

    interface ConnectionStateListener {
        void onAvailable(boolean isAvailable);
    }

    ConnectionUtil(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mConnectivityMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        ((AppCompatActivity) mContext).getLifecycle().addObserver(this);
    }


    void onInternetStateListener(ConnectionStateListener listener) {
        mNetworkStateReceiver = new NetworkStateReceiver(listener);
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        // Registering the Context Registered Receiver
        mContext.registerReceiver(mNetworkStateReceiver, intentFilter);
    }


    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
    public void onDestroy() {

        // Removing lifecycler owner observer
        ((AppCompatActivity) mContext).getLifecycle().removeObserver(this);

        // Unregistering the Context Registered Receiver
        if (mNetworkStateReceiver != null)
            mContext.unregisterReceiver(mNetworkStateReceiver);

    }


    public class NetworkStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        ConnectionStateListener mListener;

        public NetworkStateReceiver(ConnectionStateListener listener) {
            mListener = listener;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
                NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = mConnectivityMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

                if (activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    // Connected to the internet
                    mListener.onAvailable(true);

                } else if (intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, Boolean.FALSE)) {
                    // Not connected to the internet
                    mListener.onAvailable(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Manifest permission**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

**Usage:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ConnectionUtil mConnectionMonitor = new ConnectionUtil(this);
        mConnectionMonitor.onInternetStateListener(new ConnectionUtil.ConnectionStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAvailable(boolean isAvailable) {
                if(isAvailable)
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Note: [`NetworkInfo`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo) is deprecated as of API 29, and you can use [`ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback) with its [`onAvailable()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback#onAvailable(android.net.Network)) & [`onLost()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback#onLost(android.net.Network)) callbacks for the same purpose instead of using a `BroadcastReceiver`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32547006/connectivitymanager-getnetworkinfoint-deprecated/#answer-54641263) can guide to target this purpose.